# rails to_param for specific route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two routes:

```
/votes/:id/upvote
/votes/:id/downvote
```

the `votes` controller is going to handle different `votable` models.
What I'd like to do is make `upvote_path(@model)` to become `/votes/"model_class"_"model_id"/upvote`

this could be done by overriding `to_param` in a specific model like so:

```
def to_param
  "#{self.class.name.downcase}_#{self.id}"
end
```

but this would mean I'd have to do that for all `votable` models, plus I don't want other routes to be affected. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to helper code:

```
def upvote_path(model)
  "/votes/#{self.class.name.downcase}_#{self.id}/upvote"
end
```

Comment: It should be:

def upvote_path(model)
  "/votes/#{model.class.name.downcase}_#{model.id}/upvote"
end